# Google Cloud Speech Command

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Google Cloud Platform Speech command [listen] and [listen-infinite] at C# Can these two options be voice-recognized right away and stored in a variable without audio-recording files?
I'm going to make a program that compares stored voice data and represents it on a kiosk.
I referred to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api

My project's name is Voice recognitive kiosk. I was tried Azure cognitive Speech service but Azure don't support Korean language.
but Azure can do without voice .wav files.

Comment: Neither of those samples use files - they recognize speech that's recorded directly from the microphone. I suggest you clone the code, read it carefully and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speech-to-text API can use both audio files and audio content (bytes) in audio [recognition requests](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio) and [streaming recognition requests](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#streamingrecognizerequest). As @Jon pointed out, the samples referred at Github contains examples for both, using files and getting the audio directly from the [microphone](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/Recognize/InfiniteStreaming.cs).

An important thing to consider is that the [Speech API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize#performing_streaming_speech_recognition_on_an_audio_stream) are in an Alpha release state, and are not recommended for use in a production environment as they may change in the future.

Comment: The banner is unfortunately incorrect - the client libraries are GA, at least for C#. We're planning a breaking change in the next few months across all our C# client libraries, which will mean a new SemVer major version, but the 1.x Speech library is stable. (We're looking at how to address places where our docs lag behind reality in terms of releases.)